# Select multiple rows with same wildcard one time foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database like this:

```
banner     |  image  |  date
------------------------------
123_first  |  xxxxx  |  date
123_second |  xxxxx  |  date
134_foo    |  xxxxx  |  date
134_foo    |  xxxxx  |  date
134_bar    |  xxxxx  |  date
```

I need to get:

```
banner     |  image  |  date
-----------------------------
134_foo    |  xxxxx  |  date
134_bar    |  xxxxx  |  date
```

When I select a specific ID (the 134).
So I need to get all the banners id only on the first occurrence of each one.

I'm using this PDO statment but it doesn't return anything:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `banner` FROM `abanners` WHERE `banner` LIKE ? ORDER BY `date` DESC GROUP BY `banner`');
$sth->execute(array($user["id"] . "%"));
```

The result should be:

```
Array('134_foo', '134_bar');
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: in the first place, why are you combining the id with the banner? it should be two separate columns.

Comment: Yep, string comparison is expensive. bad design

Comment: those are records of the clicks on the banners, so I get which banner was clicked, and when.

Comment: and with this query I should get all the banners of a specific user.

Comment: the way you are doing will return all records like `1345_xxxx`

Comment: Should work (correct code to "GROUP BY")

Comment: was a typo but it doesn't work however.

Comment: Ok, try first GROUP BY, than ORDER BY ... `LIKE ? GROUP BY banner ORDER BY date DESC `. Actually you should get an SQL error.

Comment: Thanks, it returns me `array ( 0 => array ( 'banner' => '1234_test', ), 1 => array ( 'banner' => '1234_test2', ), )`, how can I get only the list of **ID** s? I've tried without `fetchAll();` and it returns me this associative array...

Comment: An array build of IDs only?

Comment: I need `Array('1234_test','1234_test2');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$id = $user["id"];
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `banner` FROM `abanners` 
                     WHERE `banner` LIKE ? ORDER BY `date` DESC GROUP BY `banner`');
$sth->execute(array("$id%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unique ID, you could get an array of 'banner` like this:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT `ID-hope_you_have_one`, `banner` FROM `abanners` WHERE `banner` LIKE ? ORDER BY `date` DESC GROUP BY `banner`');

$sth->execute(array($user["id"] . "%"));

$array_indexed_by_id = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

Comment: `banner` is the id of the banner.

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` needs two selected columns, I need only the `banner` column...

Comment: That's bad design, because your rows are not uniquely identifiable. You will run into several problems or even lose data, if you keep it like this.

Comment: Yeah, but the first column (if INT) would be just the array index and the second the value like `ARRAY(0=>banner1_id, 1=>banner2_id)`

Comment: those are records of clicks, how should I make them uniuque? I just need to count them and get the collected data. I'm not storing the data of my banners here.

Comment: Add an autoincrement column to your table structure.

Comment: and what's the utility of have an unique value? I don't need it, I will never fetch a data using that unique id

Comment: I told you that you need it, if you think you don't ... good luck ;)

Comment: I've already all working, I just need to get the array structured in the right way, so with just the list of fetched IDs.

Comment: So loop through the result and build an array in that way you want it. This is just the basics of ...

Comment: no, the basic should be structure the query to get the Array as I need without use PHP for it.

Comment: But unfortunately it's not, still in 2013. At least I didn't find any other ways than the two I told you. And you should add that ID anyway ;)

Comment: If you'll find a direct pdo/sql way for this, please inform me ... I am looking for this for years!